# Keeping tables together on one page - Report Builder

Tags: sql-server, reportbuilder3.0

stumped on this one.  I know there has to be a logical reason or solution to this but it has left me scratching my head.  I am using Report Builder 3.0 to build a report that will display information for a particular individual on each page.  Meaning new page for each individual.

Anyway, I currently have 4 small tables across the top of the page until I reach the right margin. For an additional table, I place it underneath the first table on the left in the top row.  Even though there is enough room vertically to contain the information from the tables in the first row and the table in the second row, it wont display that second row table until it returns a page for each individual, then it will put that data on a page of its own.

Example, if I have say 20 individuals returned, it will show the top row of tables on the first 20 pages, then starting on page 21 it will finally show the data from the table in the second row and so on.

I hope this makes sense! Any feedback or thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

| Table 1 | Table 2 | Table 3 | Table 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | First | First | First |
| Second | Second | Second | Second |

| Table 5 |
| --- |
| First |
| Second |

This is the layout as it looks like in design mode.  When I render the report, tables 1-4 will display on first page, but table 5 will not display on that page, but a second page. As far as I have been able to tell, all table data should fall within the body of the page when taking page size and margins into account.

EDIT: Each of these tables do have a Group based on the individuals name column. Also, if I were to slightly overlap the top of table 5 with the bottom of table 1, it will display the tables on the same page.